# Why the combination of two mavern dependencies makes the program stop working?

Tags: java, maven, processing, owl, owl-api

I have the problem, because I work on a Java project, I use Maven to manage dependencies, and after adding one I had output like that:

> Process finished with code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

What I did is I merged two of my projects that worked. One of this projects uses Processing for drawing some images, and the other uses OWL API to work with ontologies.

I found out, that whis two dependencies are problematc:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
        <artifactId>code-generation</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

If they are apart - in separate projects, everything works. If I add them to one pom file, I've got the Proces finished ... message.

My question is do you know why this happens and is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Please share the pom file or (at the very least) the full list of dependencies included. Otherwise it's not possible to answer your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if the dependencies of this two are conflicting, in this case, one is omitted and the oldest version is kept:

```
(org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.10)
```

You can solve this exluding the offending dependency in one of the projects:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>edu.stanford.protege</groupId>
   <artifactId>code-generation</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
   <exclusions>
     <exclusion>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

I can't test if this is the problem, but hope this can help.

Comment: Usually such dependency conflict does not crash JVM.
`Process finished with code -1073740791 (0xC0000409` - this is not from maven. 
This could be IDE\configuration issue.

Comment: That sort of conflict might be a problem, but specifically SLF4J wouldn't cause a crash - all the 1.7 versions are backwards compatible. As ssz mentioned, that error might depend on something else entirely. Which is why I asked the OP to add the pom file to the question.